# Record Error from CMD in output with Python

Tags: python, pandas, exception, cmd, error-handling

I am trying to run the below code - and what it does is run the commands in a file line by line and extract the results from the cmd into a new file. the command looks something like this 'ping (host name)' with many hosts and a line for each host.

some hosts fail in the cmd, as in it cannot find a response - usually when that happens the code breaks, so that is why I have the **try and except below.** but I am struggling to make the except section record the failed items in the same document (if possible).

so for example if ping (host name3) failed - I want it to record that message and store in the file.

If you have a better way of doing all of this please let me know!

```
command_path = pathlib.Path(r"path to the file with commands")
command_file = command_path.joinpath('command file.txt')

commands = command_file.read_text().splitlines()
#print(commands)
try: 
    for command in commands:
    #Args = command.split()
    #print(f"/Running: {Args[0]}")

    outputfile = subprocess.check_output(command) 
    print(outputfile.decode("utf-8"))
    results_path = command_path.joinpath(f"Passed_Results.txt")
    results = open(results_path, "a")
    results.write('\n' + outputfile.decode("utf-8"))
    results.close()

  except:
     #this is where I need help.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a response on a different question that I was able to augment into this. I essentially broke my entire code down and rewrote as follows. this worked for me, **However** if you are able to provide insight on a faster processing time for this. **PLEASE LET ME KNOW**

```
cmds_file = pathlib.Path(r"C:\Users'path to file here').joinpath("Newfile.txt")

 output_file = pathlib.Path(r"C:\Users'path to file 
 here').joinpath("All_Results.txt")
 with open(cmds_file, encoding="utf-8") as commands, open(output_file, "w", 
 encoding="utf-8") as output:
 for command in commands:
    command = shlex.split(command)
    output.write(f"\n# {shlex.join(command)}\n")
    output.flush()
    subprocess.run(command, stdout=output, encoding="utf-8")
```